# Error in installing scrapy on Mac 10.9.2. Bugtrack_url error

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

I am trying to install scrapy but i am getting an error when Mac OS 10.9.2 fails to install libxml2. After reading few posting on libxml2 i have installed Command Line tools but still no luck.

Please find stack of the error

```
============================
sudo easy_install -U Scrapy
Searching for Scrapy
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/Scrapy/
Best match: Scrapy 0.22.2
Processing Scrapy-0.22.2-py2.7.egg
Scrapy 0.22.2 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
Installing scrapy script to /usr/local/bin

Using /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Scrapy-0.22.2-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for Scrapy
Searching for lxml
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/lxml/
Best match: lxml 3.3.3
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/l/lxml/lxml-3.3.3.tar.gz#md5=f2675837b4358a5ecab5fd9a783fd0e5
Processing lxml-3.3.3.tar.gz
Running lxml-3.3.3/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-eyJrzG/lxml-3.3.3/egg-dist-tmp-LQSFBP
Building lxml version 3.3.3.
Building without Cython.
Using build configuration of libxslt 1.1.28
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'bugtrack_url'
  warnings.warn(msg)
clang: error: unknown argument: '-mno-fused-madd' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
=============================
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
export CFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments
export CPPFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments
sudo -E easy_install -U Scrapy
```

Pretty much every easy_install/pip install needs these options on Mac OS X 10.9.2, and "-E" to sudo is to propagate these exports to superuser environment.